# Organizing Classes and Objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, object, organization

I am a beginner with Ruby on Rails. I have a question regarding organizing objects and classes.

I have an Article class that has a few fields, like author, keywords, date, etc.

The problem is that I want to organize these article objects to be able to analyze them collectively. The articles come from different sources and I want to be able to access them based on the source.

I am guessing I can have a new class for ArticleSource and relate it to the Article class through relationships such as has_one or embeds_one. Am I doing this right, or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of "source"?  Would the New York Times be an example article source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `has_many` and `belongs_to` will do what you want.

After adding an `article_source_id` column to the Article table, your classes would look something like this:

```
class ArticleSource
  has_many :articles
end

class Article
  belongs_to :article_source
end
```

Then you can analyze the articles collectively using code like this:

```
source = ArticleSource.find_by_name("New York Times");
articles = source.articles
```

Comment: Follow up question: How do I create the sources? Do I need to set the field in the controller? like article.article_source.create()?

Comment: No, that would give an error because article_source would be nil.  You can do this:
`source = ArticleSource.create! :name => "New York Times"; article.article_source = source`   or  `article.article_source_id = source.id`.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie, but do you have sample code of this? or could you point me to a tutorial? Thank you.

Comment: I just gave you sample code for everything except the migration.  What more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into single table inheritance here.

Keep Article as a super class and inherit it into sub classes as ExtertArticle(source is expert) and StudentArticle etc...

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: I think this is more complicated than necessary.  Why do you think "source" should be such a special attribute of Article that it deserves to be treated like this?  What if the developer has another attribute like "format" (e.g. web, magazine, blog post); what makes "source" more important than "format"?